# Не могу выполнить импорт с GitLab

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab

При попытке клонирования проекта с *gitlab.com* в `IntelliJ` выходит ошибка:

> Can't login using given credentials: Request response: 401 Unauthorized - 401 Unauthorized

В настройках GitLab нету, только GitHub, там указал `Host: https://gitlab.com`, ввел логин/пароль (они верные), через токен пробовал тоже никак.

Comment: открывается, пока могу вручную скачать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно исправить логин или пароль в диспетчере учетных данных Windows. Путь: *Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей\Диспетчер учетных данных*. У меня логин с ошибкой был, вот IDEA и пыталась по нему постоянно подключатся

Answer (score 1):

В `Idea` не надо в настройках менять параметры `GitHub`. Можно просто в настройках проекта добавить удалённый репозиторий:

**`VCS` ⇒ `Git` ⇒ `Remotes`**

[image: Git remotes]

---

Можно ещё новый проект из удалённого репозитория создать:

**`File` ⇒ `New` ⇒ `Project from Version Control` ⇒ `Git`**

[image: Project from Version Control]

Comment: При первом способе выходит ошибка: Remote URL test failed: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/*******.java/********.git/'. Второй способ аналогичный тому что я уже пробовал. По сути та же проблема с авторизацией

Comment: Без прокси. Кстати в первом методе у меня спрашивало логин/пароля, хотя по логике должно.

Comment: В браузере нет прокси